# Detect Sync error in Sync Center (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, powershell, synchronization

So the current system used stores users "My Documents" and other files in a personal drive and on a server. We use Microsoft's Sync Center to ensure both "My Documents" and the personal drive contain the most current data.

The problem is sometimes remote users don't connect to our server(they need to access our VPN to do so). This causes a problem with synchronization. It's very time consuming to check one person at a time on Microsoft's Sync Center.

Is there a way to automate detection? Maybe a Cmdlet?

Comment: Maybe describe the "problem with synchronization" in general?

Comment: Did so thanks for the review and tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that one can Auto Detect errors with a Event Log. This will create a notification of the issue when it occurs!
Heres a link to set it up with vista... the principles are the same though.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/02/18/how-to-enable-event-logging-for-offline-files-client-side-caching-in-windows-vista/